# vector of functions fortran

Tags: c++, function, fortran

I recently ran across a term called "vector of functions" which I had never heard of before. I need to define a "vector of functions" to solve a system of non-linear algebraic equation. Numerical Recipes has a routine called "newt" that does this.  In C++, Numerical Recipes defines a new class of vector of functions for me, so all I have to do is call nr3.h using the library provided. Does someone know how to do this in Fortran90/95/03/08 (any of these standards works for me)? I'd like to know because I'm not well versed in C++ and so I would rather work in Fortran.

The code for C++ can be found here:
http://numerical.recipes/forum/showthread.php?t=1703&highlight=403

Notice in the code the function "VecDoub y(3)". This is not native to C++ (I don't think). However, because of the ability in C++ to define new classes, VecDoub is defined in C++. Is there a way to do this in Fortran?

Thanks.

Comment: All code needs to be posted here directly as text, and ideally as an [mcve].

Comment: A quick look at that link and a couple of google searches says that `VecDoub` is essentially a `std::vector<double>` in C++, obfuscated by the use of some pretty awkward non-standard type definitions.     The nearest (approximate) equivalent in Fortran would be a matrix of `double precision`.   The `newt` function doesn't do anything with a vector of functions.   It accepts a single function, which accepts a `VecDoub` as an argument, and returns a `VecDoub`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Peter said in the comment, there is nothing special about that "vector of functions". `VecDoub` is little more than a regular vector of doubles, and `vecfunc` is actually a function of vectors. Then, `newt` is just a procedure that accepts a vector and a function of vectors.

The closest equivalent in fortran would be something like this:

```
program vector_functions
  implicit none
  logical :: check
  integer :: i
  double precision :: x(3) = [0, 5, 7], y(3)

  print *, 'Initial guess: ', x
  print *, 'Calling newt...'
  call newt(x, check, vecfunc)
  if(check) then
    print *, 'Check is true (convergence to a local minimum).'
    print *, 'Try another initial guess.'
  else
    print *, 'Check is false (a \"normal\" return).'
  end if
  print *, 'Solution from newt: ', x
  y = vecfunc(x)
  print *, 'Value of the solution vector: ', y

contains
  function vecfunc(x) result(y)
    double precision, intent(in) :: x(:)
    double precision :: y(size(x))
    y(1) = x(1) * x(2) * x(3) - 6
    y(2) = x(1) * x(1) * x(2) + x(2) * x(2) * x(3) + x(3) * x(3) * x(1) - 23
    y(3) = exp(x(1) + x(2) + x(3)) - 403    
  end
  subroutine newt(x, check, f)
    double precision, intent(inout) :: x(:)
    logical, intent(out) :: check
    interface
      function f(a)
        double precision, intent(in) :: a(:)
        double precision :: f(size(a))
      end
    end interface
    ! custom implementation of newt here...
  end
end
```